# Comparison Test Question (Theory based?)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Consider the series $$S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$$
>   $(a.)$ Use ratio test to prove that this series is convergent.
>   
> $(b.)$ Use comparison test to show that $S<2.$
>   
> $(c.)$ Write down the **exact** value of $S$.

I have a problem answering b and c.

I do not know how to approach this question. I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me how to attempt this kind of question.

Thank you!

Comment: **Hint :** Consider another series $S' = 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 +....$.     Show that each element in $S'$ is $\ge$ than each element in $S$.Can you find out the sum of $S'$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider another infinite series

$$S' = 1 + \frac12 + \frac14 +\frac18 +....$$

It is easy to see that each element of $S'$ is $\ge$ than each element in $S$

We know that the sum of $S'$ is $2 \space($ Using sum of a G.P $).$

Hence we can claim that $S < S'$ or $S < 2$.

For the last part  , recall the value of the constant $e$.

We know that

$$e = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n!}$$

Again it is easy to observe that $$S + 1 =e$$

Or $$S = e-1 \iff \boxed{\color{blue}{S = 1.71828...}}$$

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $n! \ge 2^{n-1}$ , $\forall n \ge 1$ and in particular $n! > 2^{n-1}$ , $\forall n \ge 3$

Prove by induction!

Then note that $\frac{1}{n!} \le \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ $\forall n\ge 1$ and in particular, $\frac{1}{n!} < \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ $\forall n\ge 3$

Thus $S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=2 $

For part (c), recall $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Thus, $e=1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\dots=1+S \implies S=e-1$

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!